# Replacing categorical variable names when fewer than 10 are observed in the dataset

Tags: r

I have a large data set (about 8,000 observations) where the country of origin is listed for each observation. I want to replace the country name with "other" if that country only appears in the dataset fewer than ten times.

What would be the best function or combination of functions to achieve this?

Example subset of data:

```
id  country
3   Israel
5   USA
6   USA
7   USA
8   USA
9   USA
10  USA
11  USA
12  Spain
13  Spain
14  Spain
15  Spain
16  Spain
17  Spain
17  Spain
18  Spain
18  Spain
19  Spain
19  Spain
20  Brazil
21  Brazil
22  Brazil
23  Brazil
24  Brazil
25  Brazil
26  Brazil
27  Brazil
28  Brazil
```

Comment: Is `country` character or factor at this point?

Comment: Something like `myCount <- table(dat$country)` to get counts, then `dat$country[dat$country %in% names(myCount)[myCount < 10]] <- "other"` should work if the country variable is a character.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducible example using base R, assuming a factor (which you probably want it to be):

```
d = data.frame(country=c("Israel","USA","USA","USA",
    rep("Spain",11),rep("Brazil",5)))

> table(d$country)

Brazil Israel  Spain    USA 
     5      1     11      3 


d$id = 1:nrow(d)
levels(d$country)[table(d$country) < 10]="other"
```

Gives:

```
> table(d$country)

other Spain 
    9    11
```

(I've got fewer Brazilians than in your sample data)

If `d$country` isn't a factor, do `d$country = factor(d$country)` first.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[,  .I[.N < 10], country]$V1, country := "other"][]
```

Comment: If I make a copy of `df1` with `df0=df1` before running the `setDT`, I find `df0` gets modified as well as `df1`. DT version 1.10.4. Bug?

Comment: This is under discussion elsewhere.